# Conflict of calling inner class in Java

Tags: java, arraylist, inner-classes

I am preparing for an interview and I have come across the following question:

You have two classes namely `Main.java` and `Gearbox.java`. `Gear` is an inner class which is in `Gearbox` as shown in the code. Which one of the options will execute program successfully? Options are given in `Main` class.

Just for quick note: It was given on paper, So I couldn't execute on a computer. I have run the program and found that the first option will run successfully but my question is why does other option throw an error?

Main.java

```
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Gearbox mcLaren = new Gearbox(6);

        //Option:1
        Gearbox.Gear first = mcLaren.new Gear(1, 12);
        System.out.println(first.driveSpeed(1000));

        //Option: 2
        Gearbox.Gear second = new Gearbox.Gear(2, 15);
        System.out.println(second.driveSpeed(1000));

        //Option: 3
        Gearbox.Gear third = new mcLaren.Gear(3, 17);
        System.out.println(third.driveSpeed(1000));

    }
}
```

Gearbox.java

```
public class Gearbox {
    private ArrayList<Gear> gears;
    private int maxGears;

    public Gearbox(int maxGears) {
        this.maxGears = maxGears;
        this.gears = new ArrayList<>();
    }

    public class Gear{
        private int gearNumber;
        private double ratio;

        public Gear(int gearNumber, double ratio) {
            this.gearNumber = gearNumber;
            this.ratio = ratio;
        }

        public double driveSpeed(int revs){
            return revs * (this.ratio);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: option2 `Gear is not static so it requires an instance of the outer class.`

Comment: Compiler errors are printed. Exceptions are thrown.

Answer (score 1):

With your current definition:

1. The Option:1 works successfully since you create instances of both GearBox and Gear to initialize Gearbox.Gear object:

   ```
   Gearbox.Gear first = mcLaren.new Gear(1, 12);
   System.out.println(first.driveSpeed(1000));
   ```
2. The Option:2  method of accessing the instance, expects `Gear` to be a static class within the `Gearbox` :

   ```
   Gearbox.Gear second = new Gearbox.Gear(2, 15); 
   System.out.println(second.driveSpeed(1000));
   ```
3. The Option: 3 seems to be incorrect in terms of creating an instance of `mcLaren`, instead would work if you create an instance of Gear instead as in option 1.

   ```
   Gearbox.Gear third = new mcLaren.Gear(3, 17);
   System.out.println(third.driveSpeed(1000));
   ```

***Edit***: Link provided by @Grisha in his/her answer would be helpful to learn.

Answer (score 1):

You probably should read about [java nested classes](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/nested.html).
The relevant part is:

> An instance of InnerClass can exist only within an instance of
>   OuterClass and has direct access to the methods and fields of its
>   enclosing instance.
>
> To instantiate an inner class, you must first instantiate the outer
>   class. Then, create the inner object within the outer object with this
>   syntax:
>
> `OuterClass.InnerClass innerObject = outerObject.new InnerClass();`

Answer (score 0):

**Option 2:**

the error occurs because you trying to use the inner class `Gear`. `Gear` can't exist without an instance of `GearBox` for it to belong to. If you change `public class Gear` to `public static class Gear` this error would go away.

Edit: Interestingly when you change the inner class `Gear` to `static` Option 1 would now throw an error because you are trying to create an instance from a static Class.

**Option 3**

Every time you use the keyword `new` Java will create a new object. You create an object from a class. so `new` should be followed by a class constructor. In this case, Java is looking for the class constructor in the package `mcLaren` but of course, it doesn't exist.